# How can I shift elements inside STL container

Tags: c++, stl, containers

I want to shift elements inside container on any positions to the left or right. The shifting elements are not contiguous.

e.g I have a vector {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8} and I want to shift {4,5,7} to the left on 2 positions, the expected result will be {1,4,5,2,7,3,6,8}

Is there an elegant way to solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write your own shifting function. Here's a simple one:

```
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

template <typename Container, typename ValueType, typename Distance>
void shift(Container &c, const ValueType &value, Distance shifting)
{
    typedef typename Container::iterator Iter;

    // Here I assumed that you shift elements denoted by their values;
    // if you have their indexes, you can use advance
    Iter it = find(c.begin(), c.end(), value);
    Iter tmp = it;

    advance(it, shifting);

    c.erase(tmp);

    c.insert(it, 1, value);
}
```

You can then use it like that:

```
vector<int> v;
// fill vector to, say, {1,2,3,4,5}
shift(v, 4, -2); // v = {1,4,2,3,5}
shift(v, 3, 1); // v = {1,4,2,5,3}
```

This is a naive implementation, because when shifting multiple elements, `find` will iterate many times on the beginning of the container. Moreover, it assumes that every element is unique, which might not be the case. However, I hope it gave you some hints on how to implement what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do a simple insert and then erase?

Don't forget that you'll invalidate any iterators that refer to elements above the removal or insertion point, whichever is lowest.

HTH

cheers,

Rob