# how to move everything in an array to the left once there is an empty space in the middle?

Tags: c++, arrays

A[5] has elements {a,b,c,d,e}

A[2] becomes empty, what is the the best way to move everything to the right so that they fill up the array partially leaving the empty spaces to the far left. I know how to do it with logic and loops, I was wondering if there are any commands that would do it for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A C-style array has no concept of an "empty" element. The element will always have a value. You may decide that some value denotes an empty element but that's up to you. If your "empty" placeholder value is named `empty`, you could do something along the lines of:

```
auto empty_it = std::find(std::begin(arr), std::end(arr), empty);
std::rotate(empty_it, empty_it + 1, std::end(arr));
```

This will move the first empty element to the back of the array.

You'd be much better off using a `std::vector`, `std::list`, or other standard library container. They provide functions for removing elements from the container without you having to care about shifting elements around. For example:

```
std::vector<int> v = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};
v.erase(v.begin() + 3);
for (auto& x : v) {
    std::cout << x << " ";
}
```

This will print `0 1 2 4 5 6`. The `3` has been removed from the container.

Comment: If you do care about shifting values in an stl container, this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460583/how-can-i-shift-elements-inside-stl-container

Comment: Don't forget about `std::rotate`.