# Any good function can be used to move an element in a container?

Tags: c++, std

For example, I have a vector, and I want to move the element at position 1 to a new position 3.

```
std::vector<int> v;
for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    v.push_back(i);
// move element at position 1 to 3 
// old vector: 0 1 2 3 4
// after move: 0 2 3 1 4
```

Comment: possible dup http://stackoverflow.com/questions/460583/how-can-i-shift-elements-inside-stl-container

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [std::rotate](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate)

```
std::rotate( v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 2, v.begin() + 4 );
//           ^^^^^ 1        ^^^^^ 2        ^^^^^ 3
// 1 - beginning of the range to rotate - points to '1'
// 2 - element that will be brought to beginning after rotation - points to '2'
// 3 - one past end of range to rotate - points to '4'
```

Comment: If I want to move element at position 3 to position 1, should I do that `std::rotate(v.begin() + 1, v.begin() + 3, v.begin() + 4);`?

Comment: @user1899020 Yes, that'll leave your vector as `0 3 1 2 4`

Answer (score 1):

Use the [rotate algorithm](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/rotate.html). That will rotate the elements in a given range.

Answer (score 1):

you can use std::swap two times.

```
 std::swap(v[1], v[2]);
 std::swap(v[2],v[3]);
```

Given

```
0 1 2 3 4
```

first swap:

```
0 2 1 3 4
```

second swap

```
0 2 3 1 4
```

you get what you want

If you specify a range `[i,j]`, you can put these into a function and apply swap by looping through `v[i]` to `v[j]`.